# Get QScrollArea absolute size

Tags: qt, qwidget, qscrollarea

I have a custom widget that is a child of a `QScrollArea`.
I need to get the absolute size of the `QScrollArea`, regardless of scrollbars being displayed or not.

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget { /*...*/ };

void
MyWidget::Foo()
{
    auto scrollAreaHeight = parentWidget()->height();
    auto scrollAreaWidth = parentWidget()->width();

    /* height and width change depending on scrollbars 
       being displayed or not */
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Alternatively, if this is impossible trough the `QWidget` interface returned by the `parentWidget()` function, is there a way to get a `QScrollArea`'s absolute size from the `QScrollArea` itself?

Comment: I guess the `parentWidget()` returns the `viewport` of the scrollarea. Hence, the width and height changes depending on whether scrollbars are visible. With `parentWidget()->parentWidget()->size()`, it would probably work better. However, I would consider this solution as fragile if a widget assumes a certain parent widget. May be, you should consider to derive your widget from `QAbstractScrollArea` directly to come around this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand completely why OP cannot get the absolute size of `QScrollArea`.

However, I assume there might be something missing in OP's understanding. I prepared the following small sample:

A `QWidget` with a `QVBoxLayout` with a `QScrollArea` with a `QPushButton`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QPushButton

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
qWinMain = QWidget()
qVBox = QVBoxLayout()
qScrollArea = QScrollArea()
qBtn = QPushButton("Consume somehow some space\nConsume somehow some space\nConsume somehow some space\n")
qScrollArea.setWidget(qBtn)
qVBox.addWidget(qScrollArea)
qWinMain.setLayout(qVBox)
qWinMain.show()

def onBtnClicked():
  print("Sizes:")
  print("qWinMain:               ", qWinMain.size())
  print("qWinMain.childrenRect():", qWinMain.childrenRect().size())
  print("qScrollArea:            ", qScrollArea.size())
  print("qScrollArea.viewport(): ", qScrollArea.viewport().size())
  print("qBtn:                   ", qBtn.size())

qBtn.clicked.connect(onBtnClicked)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When the `QPushButton` is clicked, some sizes of the widgets are printed.
It did this twice – once when scrollbars are invisible, and again after I changed size of main window so that scrollbars became visible.

[image: Snapshot 1 (with scrollbars not activated)] [image: Snapshot 2 (with scrollbars activated)]

Output:

```
Sizes:
qWinMain:                PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(225, 100)
qWinMain.childrenRect(): PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(203, 78)
qScrollArea:             PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(203, 78)
qScrollArea.viewport():  PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(201, 76)
qBtn:                    PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(201, 65)
Sizes:
qWinMain:                PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(120, 92)
qWinMain.childrenRect(): PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(98, 70)
qScrollArea:             PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(98, 70)
qScrollArea.viewport():  PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(82, 54)
qBtn:                    PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(201, 65)
```

So, this is how to read this:

- `qWinMain.size()` returned client area size of `qWinMain` (not considering window decorations).
- `qWinMain.childrenRect().size()` returned bounding box size of children of `qWinMain` – It's exactly 22 pixels smaller in width and height what makes sense as 11 pixels is the default margin of `QWidget`.
- `qScrollArea.size()` returned the exact same size like `qWinMain.childrenRect().size()` in both cases which is reasonable as it's the only child.
- `qScrollArea.viewport().size()` returns the viewport size of `QScrollArea` – that size is dependend on whether scrollbars are visible or not. Without scrollbars, the difference to `qScrollArea` is only 2 pixels in width and height but with scrollbars it's respectively greater.
- `qBtn.size()` returns size of push button which is independent of its visual/clipped regions and, hence, in both cases equal.

So, whatever OP meant with "absolute size of QScrollArea" – one of these should be OP is looking for.

Comment: @Unimportant Sorry, that I did it in PyQt. Actually, C++ is my "native" language. However, 1st) you didn't tag any language 2nd) Python code is even shorter 3rd) the principle doesn't change in C++.

Comment: Thanks, I need some time to grok this.

Comment: You're right, `QScrollArea::width()` and `QScrollArea::height()` return the absolute size of the scrollarea while calling `parentWidget()->width()` and `parentWidget()->height()` from within the scrollarea's child widget returns the scrollarea' s viewport size. That sent me on a wild goosechase.